# How do you stack Extreme Networks Summit 200 switches?

Tags: networking, switch

Read through the manual, and in the intro/feature list, they mention that these can be stacked (and the LED display diagram suggests that the master will show 01, and any slaves 02, etc.) but there's no indication of how to actually stack them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it was in this document (Rev.2, I was reading Rev.1):
http://extremenetworks.com/libraries/services/Summit200UserRev2.pdf

The 200 series isn't covered in that manual, Chopper3.